# PHP/HTML query with Oracle database, WHERE clause on data from input box

Tags: php, html, oracle

I need some help with querying data from an Oracle Database. Inside this database, I have an Employee table containing some information including azip code, id, fname, and lname fields.

My query looks like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM Employee
              WHERE Employee.lname=='.$fname;
```

I am reading information from the input text box I have generated in HTML. I want to read the input, and retrieve the information for an employee with the name that has been entered in the input box.

It doesn't seem to like my query, as it is not returning any results. Any help here?

Note: Ignore any of the connection strings associated with logging into the database. These have been removed for security concerns. The login does work, as I have preformed general queries with success.

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    </style>
    </head>
    <body> 

    <?php
    $nameErr = "";
    $name = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
         $nameErr = "Name is required";
       } 
       else {
         $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
         if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
           $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
         }
       }
    }

    function test_input($data) {
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
       return $data;
    }
    ?>

    <h1>Assignment 4</h1>
    <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
       Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
       <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
       <br><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
    </form>

    <?phpasdf
    echo "<h1>Results:</h1>";
    echo $name;
    echo "<br>";
    ?>


    <?php

    // The connection string is loooooooong. It's easiest to copy/paste   this line. Remember to replace 'username' and 'password'!
    $conn = oci_connect('login', 'password', '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=host)(Port=xxxx)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=cs)))');

    //put your query in here
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM Employee
              WHERE Employee.lname=='.$fname;

    $stid = oci_parse($conn,$query);
    oci_execute($stid,OCI_DEFAULT);


    //iterate through each row
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_ASSOC)) 
    {
       //iterate through each item in the row and echo it
       foreach ($row as $item) 
       {
          echo $item; 
       }
       echo '<br/>';
    }
    oci_free_statement($stid);
    oci_close($conn);

    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: if you're using ORACLE, then why the mysql tag?

Comment: Sorry. I will remove the tag.

Comment: this `WHERE Employee.lname=='.$fname;` should use one equal sign  `"SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Employee.lname='$fname'";` and is most likely a string.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the comment, but still doesn't seem to work... we're onto something here though.

Comment: Hold on, you don't have a variable called `$fname` but `$name`.

Comment: Yep! I just noticed that too... was literally just going to comment that my $fname doesnt know what it's referring to. Hmm..

Comment: Hey man! I got it. Yep, just needed to change it to $name. $query = "SELECT * FROM Employee
    WHERE Employee.lname='$name'"; 

Thanks for the help kind sir.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll post an answer below so we can close 'er up.

Answer (score 1):

This part of your query

```
WHERE Employee.lname=='.$fname;
```

It should use one equal sign and wrapping the `$name` variable in quotes, while using double quotes for the wrapper itself:

```
"SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Employee.lname='$name'";
```

because it is a string and not an integer.

Nota: The `$fname` variable does not exist, it should have been `$name`.

As per:

```
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
```

- Using error reporting would have thrown an undefined variable fname notice.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Plus, checking for errors in the query would have thrown a syntax error.